# `sys.dont_write_bytecode` is True, but .pyc files are still generated

Tags: python

I'm setting the `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` environment variable to avoid .pyc files, and  I have checked that `sys.dont_write_bytecode` is True.

But .pyc files are still generated everywhere.

PS: I'm using Python 2.6.6

**The reason is that my script is running under `env -i`.**

Comment: Have you tried adding `-B` to your "sh-bang"? `#!/usr/bin/env python -B`

Answer (score 13):

It should appear before importing your modules. I have moved it to the top of code and it works.

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

import myModule
```

Comment: This worked for me in python 3.5 in both Ubuntu 16.04 and on Windows 10.

Comment: Are there any unintended consequences of importing `sys` for each module or in `ipython` during/before startup?

Comment: For python 2 I just add it  on first module, it is a global option of interpreter

Answer (score 5):

It could be that you are mispelling the env variable? `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`

This works:
`PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 python -c "import test"`

So does this: `python -B -c "import test"`

And when running a script directly which imports test.py:
`./importer.py`

*importer.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -B

import test
```

Comment: I've checked that sys.dont_write_bytecode is True, so typo may not be the problem here.

Comment: Will Python evaluate the hashbang in case of Windows, for example?

Comment: @0xC0000022L no windows does not support shebang lines in scripts, unless you were running it under a Linux subshell.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from making sure to spell it correctly, are you sure the variable is actually being exported, rather than merely set?

For example, if using bash, try:

```
export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
```

or:

```
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE
```